# Is there a way to run a function if the user of my webpage hits a certain point on it?

Tags: javascript, html

I try do a webite with different divs or for me they are sections. If I reached the top of one of these it should console log this term. If u ask, ScrollHeight is equal to 1% of the devices' screenheight.

```
let Point1 = false;
document.addEventListener("scroll", e=> {
if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 150*ScrollHeight) {
    if (Point1 == false){
        Point1 = true;
        Point1F();
    };
}
})
function Point1F() {
console.log("U've done it');
}
```

But its not woking for me.

Comment: You haven't defined `ScrollHeight` in this code. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Idiomatic JavaScript reserves variable names starting with a capital letter for constructor functions and classes. Don't use them for holding data.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, as i think the problem why you don't see your .log() is because you didn't reach it.

If scrollHeight is (as you said) "1% of the devices' screenheight", then you need html height to be ~ 3x your screen height;

```
document.documentElement.style.height = "300vh";

// getting 1% of screen height
const scrollHeight = screen.height / 100; 
const scrollTriggerPoint = scrollHeight * 150;

let point1 = false;

document.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >= scrollTriggerPoint) {
    if (point1 == false){
        point1 = true;
        point1F();
    };
  }
});

function point1F() {
  console.log("u've done it");
}
```

P.S.

Don't use variable's/function's names starting with a capital letter, use it on;y for constructor functions or classes.

Answer (score 1):

**Intersection Observer API**

Using scroll position is fine when you have a single trigger point. However, when there are multiple trigger points (as the question suggests) and they are not in a consistent position on different devices, then the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) is a useful solution.

**MDN:**

> Implementing intersection detection in the past involved event
> handlers and loops calling methods like
> Element.getBoundingClientRect() to build up the needed information for
> every element affected. Since all this code runs on the main thread,
> even one of these can cause performance problems. When a site is
> loaded with these tests, things can get downright ugly.

You create an observer on the document or a container element and then add the elements you want to watch. And the callback is triggered when an element reaches the threshold setting.

**Demo Snippet**

The snippet shows how to observe different sections as they scroll in and out of view.

```js
// create an observer on the document or container element

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
  if (entry.isIntersecting) {

    // code to execute when the section becomes visible

    console.log("is visible: " + entry.target.id);
    
    // uncomment to trigger only once per section
    // observer.unobserve(entry.target); 
  }
}, {
  root: document,  // or container element or null
  rootMargin: "0px",
  threshold: 0.1
});

// add each section to the observer

document.querySelectorAll("section").forEach(target => {
  observer.observe(target);
});
```

```css
section {
  height: 5em;
  margin: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 20em;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
Scroll down the page to trigger the observer

<section id="section1">Section 1</section>
<section id="section2">Sectopm 2</section>
<section id="section3">Section 3</section>
<section id="section4">Section 4</section>
<section id="section5">Section 5</section>
```

Comment: Ok, and how could I do a different thing for every section? I got 10 of those divs and everyone should run a different one

Comment: Ok, thanks, U dont need to answer on the first comment. The first answer worked aswell. Thanks for investing your time.